# How to set the value of a component binding inline without a variable reference?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

If I have a component laid out like so

```
module my.component {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('example')
        .component('customcomponent',
        {
            templateUrl: 'some/folder/structure/withmyfile.html',
            controller: 'componentController',
            bindings: {
                myBinding: '<'
            }
        });
}
```

And the controller, `componentController` is designed like this

```
module my.component {
    'use strict';

    class ComponentController {
        myBinding: string;

        $onInit = () => {
            console.log(this.myBinding);
        };
    }

    angular.module('example')
        .controller('componentController', ComponentController);
}
```

I'm not able to set my binding inline without using a variable reference it seems. If I call my component in another html file, and try to set the binding's value like this

```
<customcomponent my-binding="test"></customcomponent>
```

my goal is that the component would be called, the controller would be executed, and the value, `"test"` would pass from the inline declaration in the html, to the variable, `myBinding` in the controller.

So that when `console.log(this.myBinding);` executes the console should read the word, `"test"` and would be of type string.

These are the various ways I've tried to accomplish this, and none so far have worked.

```
<customcomponent my-binding="test"></customcomponent>
<customcomponent my-binding="\'test\'"></customcomponent>
<customcomponent my-binding="{{test}}"></customcomponent>
<customcomponent my-binding="{{"test"}}"></customcomponent>
<customcomponent my-binding="{{\"test\"}}"></customcomponent>
```

So is it possible to set the value for the binding inline similar to how one might set the value for a `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: Change `bindings: {
                myBinding: '<'
            }` to `bindings: {
                myBinding: '='
            }`. And then try this `<customcomponent my-binding="'test'"></customcomponent>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bind to a string with a value of `test`, use one-way, `'<'`, binding with the string quoted:

```
<customcomponent my-binding="'test'">
</customcomponent>
```

```
app.component('customcomponent',
{
    templateUrl: 'some/folder/structure/withmyfile.html',
    controller: 'componentController',
    bindings: {
        myBinding: '<'
    }
});
```

Or use attribute, `'@'`, binding without quotes:

```
<customcomponent my-binding="test">
</customcomponent>
```

```
app.component('customcomponent',
{
    templateUrl: 'some/folder/structure/withmyfile.html',
    controller: 'componentController',
    bindings: {
        myBinding: '@'
    }
});
```

## The Demo

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.component('customcomponent', {
        template:
            `<div>my-binding={{$ctrl.myBinding}}
            </div>`       
        ,
        controller: function($scope) {
            this.$onInit = () => {
                console.log("my-binding=",this.myBinding);
            };
        },
        bindings: {
            myBinding: '<'
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <customcomponent my-binding="'test'">
    </customcomponent>
</body>
```